# Problemas com o Scanner do Java

Tags: java

Estou tendo problemas na hora de compilar um programa de leitura básico escrito em java, quando compilo ele dá erros de continuidade no console.

```
package programa_leitura;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome;
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("Como gostaria de ser chamado?");
        nome = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Seja bem vindo(a) "+nome);
        System.out.println("Para onde deseja ir? (w/a/s/d)");
        String comando = in.nextLine();
        String yn = in.nextLine();
        if(comando.equals("w")){//direção W
            System.out.println("Você anda alguns metros em direção norte...");
            System.out.println("Você se depara com uma espada meio enferrujada, deseja pega-la? (y/n)");
            if (yn.equals ("y")){
                System.out.println("Você obteve 'espada enferrujada'!");
                System.out.println("[O\\\\\\\\\\[========================-");}
            else if(yn.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Você passa reto pela espada enferrujada");}
            else {
                System.out.println("Comando não reconhecido, digite novamente");
                if (yn.equals("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Você obteve 'espada enferrujada'!");
                    System.out.println("[O\\\\\\\\\\[========================-");}
                else if(yn.equals("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Você passa reto pela espada enferrujada");}
                }
        }
        else if(comando.equals("a")){//direção A
            System.out.println("Você anda alguns metros em direção oeste e chega em um bosque ...");
            System.out.println("Quer continuar? (y/n)");
            if (yn.equals("y")){
                System.out.println("Você encontra as ruínas de algo que parece ser uma aldeia...");
                System.out.println("Você encontra uma casa quase que em perfeito estado");
                System.out.println("Deseja entrar? (y/n)");
                if(yn.equals("y")){
                    System.out.println("");}

            else {
                System.out.println("Você acha melhor para por ai e volta para casa.");
                System.out.println("Obrigado por jogar!");}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: erro parte 1]
Por enquanto tudo certo
[image: erro parte 2]
Aqui é necessário apertar enter duas vezes para continuar
[image: erro parte 3]
Esses dois últimos eram pra ser divididos, porém por algum motivo não é isso que acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você fez duas chamadas seguidas de [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()):

```
String comando = in.nextLine();
String yn = in.nextLine();
```

Cada vez que você chama `nextLine`, o programa fica esperando você digitar alguma coisa para prosseguir. Então primeiro você digita o comando, e logo em seguida ele fica esperando você digitar outra coisa (e isso é feito antes dos próximos `println`).

Para corrigir, retire essa segunda chamada de `nextLine`, e coloque-o nos locais corretos (logo depois das respectivas mensagens, que é quando você de fato precisa ler alguma coisa):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println("Como gostaria de ser chamado?");
String nome = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Seja bem vindo(a) " + nome);
System.out.println("Para onde deseja ir? (w/a/s/d)");
String comando = in.nextLine();
String yn = "";
if (comando.equals("w")) {// direção W
    System.out.println("Você anda alguns metros em direção norte...");
    System.out.println("Você se depara com uma espada meio enferrujada, deseja pega-la? (y/n)");
    yn = in.nextLine(); // <---------- AQUI
    if (yn.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Você obteve 'espada enferrujada'!");
        System.out.println("[O\\\\\\\\\\[========================-");
    } else if (yn.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Você passa reto pela espada enferrujada");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Comando não reconhecido, digite novamente");
        yn = in.nextLine(); // <---------- AQUI TAMBÉM
        if (yn.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Você obteve 'espada enferrujada'!");
            System.out.println("[O\\\\\\\\\\[========================-");
        } else if (yn.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Você passa reto pela espada enferrujada");
        }
    }
} else if (comando.equals("a")) {// direção A
    System.out.println("Você anda alguns metros em direção oeste e chega em um bosque ...");
    System.out.println("Quer continuar? (y/n)");
    yn = in.nextLine(); // <---------- AQUI TAMBÉM
    if (yn.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Você encontra as ruínas de algo que parece ser uma aldeia...");
        System.out.println("Você encontra uma casa quase que em perfeito estado");
        System.out.println("Deseja entrar? (y/n)");
        yn = in.nextLine(); // <---------- E AQUI TAMBÉM
        if (yn.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Você acha melhor para por ai e volta para casa.");
            System.out.println("Obrigado por jogar!");
        }
    }
}
```